# TVTopShelfCarouselItem title display on top of image

Tags: tvos, tvos13

I have implemented a tvOS 13 fullscreen top shelf extension with `TVTopShelfCarouselItem`s that have a `imageURL` and a `previewVideoURL` set.

The item's `title` however is only displayed when the video is playing, not while the image is shown. It doesn't matter if the items have or don't have a `previewVideoURL` set.

The behaviour is different in Apple's TV app that show's the title also on top of the image (for movies that don't have the title in the poster).

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

After further investigation of Apple's TV app behaviour, it seems that Apple works around this issue by embedding the title in the image.

Because the title on top of the image is also visible when the information overlay is hidden.

I filled an enhancement request feedback with Apple.